# *ngFor error al renderizar los objetos de la base de datos en el frontend (Node.js) (Angular)

Tags: nodejs, angular, ionic, express, ngfor

Hola buen dia llevo ya un rato intentando solucionar este problema, pero no he podido, agradesco de antemano su colaboracion.

Problema:
Cuando intento renderizar mis objetos de mi backend (node.js express), por medio de un ion-card (Ionic(Angular)) utilizando la directiva *ngFor obtengo el siguiente error:

> "ERROR Error: "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Esto ocurre cuando consumo un servicio GET de mi backend.

Codigo

//Node.js metodo get

```
app.get('/usuario', (req, rep) => {
    console.log('Metodo Get');

    //si se coloca en el find {estado:true} mostrara solo los registros con esta propiedad
    //util para ver los usuario activos en la base de datos
    User.find({}, 'id nombre apellido correo direccion telefono estado')
        .exec((err, usuariosDB) => {
            if (err) {
                return rep.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    err
                });
            }

            if (usuariosDB === 0 || usuariosDB === undefined || usuariosDB === null) {
                return rep.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    err: 'No hay usuarios en la base de datos'
                });
            }

            rep.json({
                usuariosDB
            });
        });
```

---

//ANGULAR servicio para consumir el get

```
public environment = environment;
  constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }


  getAllUsers(): Observable <Usuario[]> {
    console.log(this.environment.endpointUsuarios.url);
    return this.http.get<Usuario[]>(this.environment.endpointUsuarios.url);
  }
```

---

//ANGULAR metodo de mi componenete para utilizar el servicio

```
export class Tab1Component implements OnInit {
  public usuarios: Usuario[];
  constructor( private usuario: UsuariosService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllUsuarios();
  }


  public getAllUsuarios(): void {
    this.usuario.getAllUsers()
    .subscribe((resp) => {
      this.usuarios = resp;
      console.log(resp);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(`metodo getAllUsuarios error ${err}`);
    });
  }
}

-- -
```

//HTML del componenete en el cual quiero utilizar el ngFor

```html
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col> </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>

<ion-content>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios">
            <ion-col>
                <ion-card>
                    <ion-card-content>
                        <ion-label>Nombre: {{ usuario.nombre }}</ion-label>
                        <ion-label>Apellido: {{ usuario.apellido }}</ion-label>
                        <ion-label>Telefono: {{ usuario.telefono }}</ion-label>
                    </ion-card-content>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>

<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="12">
            <ion-button color="tertiary" expand="block" fill="solid" (click)="getAllUsuarios()"> Completar Registro </ion-button>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>




<app-footer> </app-footer>
```

---

\Interfaz de Usuario

```
export class Usuario {
        id: number;
        nombre: string;
        apellido: string;
        telefono: string;
        contrasena: string;
}
```

Muchas gracias, si necesitan mas detalles solo es que me digan y dare mas detalles de ser necesario.

Muchas gracias

/// Print de la respuesta en consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes probar poniendo los elementos en un arreglo

```
.subscribe((resp) => {

resp.forEach( ( user ) => {

                this.usuarios.push( user );
            } );
    }
```

en caso que resp no sea un array puedes usar convertir en uno con Object.keys(resp) el codigo quedaria asi:

```
 .subscribe((resp) => {

    Object.keys(resp).forEach( ( user ) => {

                    this.usuarios.push( user );
                } );
        }
```

talve sea necesario hacer doble iteracion:

```
 Object.keys(resp).forEach( ( users ) => {
     Object.keys(users).forEach( ( user ) => {
                    this.usuarios.push( user );
                } );
      } );
  }
```

otra opcion es que uses Pipe

```
 this.getAllUsers().pipe(
            mergeMap(data => {
                this.listUsers = data;
                data.forEach((current: any) => {
                   listUsers.push(current);
                });
                return forkJoin(listUsers);
            })
        ).subscribe((response: any) => {
            this.usuarios = response;// o response[0]

        });
```

Comment: Hola ya utilze lo que me recomendaste,

Comment: @OmarCuadrado y que tal funciono?

Comment: en parte ya no tengo el error anterior pero tengo uno nuevo, lo cual me parece raro ...ERROR TypeError: "resp.forEach is not a function"

me parece raro porque el codigo coloque un console.log para ver la respuesta y efectivamente me trae datos...

Comment: public getAllUsuarios(): void {
    this.usuario.getAllUsers()
    .subscribe( (resp) => {

      console.log(resp);
      resp.forEach((user) => {
        console.log(user);
        this.usuarios.push(user);
      });

      }, (err) => {
      console.log(`metodo getAllUsuarios error ${err}`);
    });
  }

Comment: este es el error que ahora me esta generando

ERROR TypeError: "resp.forEach is not a function"  :P

y cuando uso el console log me da esta respuesta el obejto

{…}
​
usuariosDB: (4) […]
​​
0: Object { estado: "false", _id: "5dec166f470da42144cb1fc8", nombre: "omitar", … }
​​
1: Object { estado: "true", _id: "5dec1674470da42144cb1fc9", nombre: "omitar", … }
​​
2: Object { estado: "true", _id: "5dec7f0e7afcf0155c0fc4fb", nombre: "omitar", … }
​​
3: Object { estado: "true", _id: "5dec7f4a7afcf0155c0fc4fe", nombre: "omitar", … }
​​
length: 4

Comment: Hola bro ya hice lo que me recomendaste esta mejor por lo menos ya no hay errores, pero cuando hago esto se crea una sola salida "usuariosDB" pero es un string, como tal no es un array de objetos, creo que al realizar eso hizo un serializacion del objeto a un string,

```javascript

Comment: en codigo realize lo siguente ---

public getAllUsuarios(): void {
    this.usuario.getAllUsers()
    .subscribe((resp) => {
      Object.keys(resp).forEach( (user) => {
          console.log(user);
          this.usuarios.push( user );
          console.log(this.usuarios);

      });

Comment: @OmarCuadrado talves sea necesario hacer dos iteraciones, edite mi respuesta

Comment: hola bro relize lo que me dijiste, al hacer esto crea un arreglo con numeros 9, lo curioso es que solo tengo 4 registros, y los guarda es como un unico numero es decir, 1 , 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 etc pero no como objetos, rayos no pense que fuera tan complicado, muchas gracias por tu ayuda bro, preguntare a un amigo que programa con node y angular, quizas el problema sea la forma en la que yo envio la respuesta desde el backend

Comment: pero deberia resolverse aqui en el sitio para ayudar a los demas

Comment: totalmente de acuerdo, bueno sigamos intentando igual en caso que encuentre la solucion la posteare

Comment: @OmarCuadrado si pruebas con Object.keys(resp).forEach( ( users ) => {
    
                    this.usuarios.push( user.UsuariosDB);

      } );
  }

Comment: cuando lo intento realizar de esa manera sale lo siguiente:
Property 'UsuariosDB' does not exist on type 'string'

Comment: @OmarCuadrado edite mi respuesta revisala porfavor

Comment: Excelente bro con eso ya funciono :D +20000000000000000000000000 jjajajajja que dilema tanto enrollo para eso muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 3):

**resp** es un objeto y dentro de la propiedad usuariosDB tiene el array que necesitas

```
this.usuarios = resp.usuariosDB
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], una explicación de tu aporte lo haría lucir de mejor calidad